# Converting list of dfs from pd.read_html into dfs with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to modify pd.read_html such that it returns a dataframe instead of a list of dataframes?

Context:
I am trying to use pandas read_html to import tables from a website. I understand that pd.read_html returns a list of dfs instead of individual dataframes. I've been circumventing this by assigning the first (and only dataframe) in the list returned from pd.read_html to a new variable. However, I want to store multiple dataframes from different urls in a master dictionary (using the code below) and would like the values to be dataframe elements, not lists.

```
urls_dict = {
    '2017': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2017',
    '2016': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2016',
    '2015': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2015',
    '2014': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2014',
    '2013': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2013',
    '2012': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2012',
    '2011': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2011',
    '2010': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2010',
    '2009': 'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year=2009'        
}

dfs_dict = {}
for key, url in urls_dict.items():
   dfs_dict[key] = pd.read_html(url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension inside of [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the dataframes for each year (use `.assign(year=year)` to add the respective years as a column).

Note that `pd.read_html(url)` returns a list of dataframes. For the given urls, the length of the list is never more than one, so use `pd.read_html(url)[0]` to access the actual dataframe, then [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the year as a column.

```
dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_html(url)[0].assign(year=year) for year, url in urls_dict.items()])
```

Note that you can create `urls_dict` using the following dictionary comprehension together with [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (formatted string literals, introduced in Python 3.6):

```
years = range(2009, 2018)
urls_dict = {
    str(year): f'https://postgrad.sgu.edu/ResidencyAppointmentDirectory.aspx?year={year}' 
    for year in years
}
```

Comment: just so i understand all of this .assign(year = year) will take the year (ie the key in my dictionary of urls) as a column and will assign the year as the values in that column? also why is pd.read_html(url)[0].assign(year=year) for year, url in urls_dict.items()] in square brackets? am i creating a list of dfs to concatenate? thank you for your help!

Comment: Given your comment posted to @Datanovice, you may want to amend that to `.assign(grad_year=year)`.  The LHS is the new column name (`grad_year`) and the RHS is the variable to be assigned to that column (the given year per the keys in `urls_dict`). The expression is in square brackets `[...]` because it is a list comprehension that generates a list of dataframes, which is the imput argument to the `pd.concat` function.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can make a slight edit to your code and call `pd.concat` to concat all calls you make with `pd.read_html`

```
dfs = {}  # initlaise the loop.
# acess the key and values of a dictionary.
# in {'2017' : [1,2,3]} 2017 is the key and [1,2,3] are the values. 
for key, url in urls_dict.items(): 
# for each unique item in your dict, read in the url and concat the list using pd.concat
    dfs[key] =(pd.concat(pd.read_html(url))) 
    dfs[key]['grad_year'] = key # if you want to assign the key to a column.
    dfs[key] = dfs[key].drop('PGY',axis=1) # drop PGY.
```

---

```
print(dfs['2017'].iloc[:5,:3])
   PGY         Type                       Name
0  PGY-1  Categorical       Van Denakker, Tayler
1  PGY-1  Preliminary  Bisharat-Kernizan, Jumana
2  PGY-1  Preliminary        Schiffenhaus, James
3  PGY-1  Categorical            Collins, Kelsey
4  PGY-1  Categorical             Saker, Erfanul

type(dfs['2017'])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: thank you! now i want to drop the PGY column from each dataframe and add a new column 'grad_year' containing the grad year (ie the key)

Comment: @gboge added for you, but I think Alexander's function does that for you in a nice one liner :)

Comment: thank you again! im a python pandas novice would you mind walking me thru the for loop?

Comment: @gboge you are very welcome my man, added some comments for you - but a for loop is the quite basic, I'd suggest brushing up on the fundamentals :)

Comment: sorry to bother again but whats the purpose of df[key] im having trouble understanding that part

Comment: this is the unique `key` from your initial dict we are using to build up your dictionary of dataframes @gboge make sense?

Comment: so it acts as a placeholder?